How I can override RippleTheme for all app
I want to override RippleTheme for the entire application, but when I use clickable {} nothing happens, a ripple is used that would have been used if I hadn't specified my RippleTheme
object AppRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor(): Color = Color.Transparent

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha() = RippleAlpha(
        draggedAlpha = 0.0f,
        focusedAlpha = 0.0f,
        hoveredAlpha = 0.0f,
        pressedAlpha = 0.0f,
    )

}

@Composable
fun AndroidTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides null,
        LocalRippleTheme provides AppRippleTheme
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            typography = AppTypography,
            content = content
        )
    }
}

How I can override RippleTheme for all app?
